# refresh page when modify appbar

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change sorting of a ListView via a DropDown menu in the appbar, but it doesn't reload the page with the new settings.
this is the AppBar

```
AppBar(
    title: Image.asset('lib/assets/titolo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
    actions: [
      PopupMenuButton(
        itemBuilder: (context) {
        return const [
          PopupMenuItem<int>(
            value: 0,
            child: Text("Ordina per distanza"),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem<int>(
            value: 1,
            child: Text("Ordina per data"),
          ),              
        ];
      }, onSelected: (value) async {
        if (value == 0) {
          setState(() {
            ordinamento = "Distanza";
          });
        } else if (value == 1) {
          setState(() {
            ordinamento = "Data";
          });
        } 
      }),
    ],
  ),
```

while this is the body

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: firebaseEventi.get(),
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.hasData) {
            switch (ordinamento) {
              case "Distanza":
                listaEventi.sort(
                  (a, b) => a.distanzaTempo.compareTo(b.distanzaTempo),
                );
                break;
              case "Data":
                {
                    listaEventi.sort(
                      (a, b) => a.orari.first.data.compareTo(b.orari.first.data),
                    );
                  break;
                }
            }

            return ListView(
                children: listaEventi.map((evento) {
              return eventoListaWidget(evento);
            }).toList());
          } 
          return paginaLoading();
        },
      );
```

i tried calling the setState inside the onTap but it seems it just reloads the appbar

Comment: why is the onSelected in the appBar, async?

Comment: inside there is an async function but I eliminated it to simplify the code

Comment: ah ok. did you confirm that your future is being rebuilt, like put a print statement above the if(snap.hasData), i am wondering if the set state is not retriggering the future. i do something similar with my filtering, but i pass the values into the future, which is the only difference.